# Google Calendar API attachments

Tags: api, calendar, attachment

I can add an attachment to a calanedar event by using the labs enable event attachment.
However, it seems the details of the attachment are not available via the API when calling a list of events.
Are there any plans to add this functionality to the API? Is there another way of adding a link or a hidden field to an event that is available via the API.

thanks

Comment: I am also wondering about this.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: same problem. in a case if you get any solution then please post it here.